# CsvHelper - Read multiple related columns into a list of objects

Tags: .net, csvhelper

I have a CSV like this: (*note: actual csv has 5 of each of the repeating columns instead of just 2*)

```
Id Name Diagnosis 1 Diagnosis 2 Drug 1 Drug 2 How Taken 1 How Taken 2
== ==== =========== =========== ====== ====== =========== ===========
 1 One  F23         F25         D1     D55    Oral        Inject
 2 Two  F30                     D5     D7     Inject      Inhale
```

I'm using CsvHelper to map this into my POCO object that looks like this:

```cs
public class Episode {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IList<string> Diagnoses {get; set;}
    public IList<Drug> Drugs { get; set;}
}

public class Drug {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string AdministrationMethod {get; set;}
}
```

I've seen a couple references of mapping to IEnumerable with CsvHelper but there is no formal documentation on it.

Is there any way to:

1. Map Diagnosis 1, Diagnosis 2, etc. to the `IList<string> Diagnoses` property?
2. Map [Drug x, How Taken x] pairs to the `IList<Drug> Drugs` property?

The following is as close as I know how to come (definitely doesn't work but trying to help give the concept of what I'm after).

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EpisodeMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<EpisodeMap>();
    }
}

public EpisodeMap : ClassMap<Episode>{
    public EpisodeMap(){
      Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");
      Map(m => m.Diagnoses).Name("Diagnosis").Index(5);  //Unsure how to indicate appropriate name "Diagnosis {index}"
      References<DrugMap>(m => m.Drugs).Index(5); //?? Not sure if something like this is possible
    }
}

public DrugMap : ClassMap<Drug> {
    public DrugMap() {
       Map(m => m.Name).Name("Drug");
       Map(m => m.AdministrationMethod).Name("How Taken");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `Index()` only works with simple IEnumerables like `IEnumerable<string>`. You are going to need to use `ConvertUsing()` for more complex objects, either utilizing the name or index of the column. `Name()` should have worked for `Diagnosis`, but for some reason I can only get it to work if the heading columns are named the same as the property `Diagnoses`.

You could also use `ConvertUsing()` to get `Diagnosis` headings to work.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, new Configuration()))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,Name,Diagnoses 1,Diagnoses 2,Drug 1,Drug 2,How Taken 1,How Taken 2");
            writer.WriteLine("1,One,F23,F25,D1,D55,Oral,Inject");
            writer.WriteLine("2,Two,F30,,D5,D7,Inject,Inhale");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<EpisodeMap>();
            csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (header, index) => Regex.Replace(header, " ", string.Empty);

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Episode>().ToList();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class EpisodeMap : ClassMap<Episode>
{
    public EpisodeMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.Name);
        Map(m => m.Diagnoses).Index(2,3);  //Unsure how to indicate appropriate name "Diagnosis {index}"
        Map(m => m.Drugs).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {
            return new List<Drug>
            {
                new Drug { Name = row["Drug1"], AdministrationMethod = row["HowTaken1"] },
                new Drug { Name = row["Drug2"], AdministrationMethod = row["HowTaken2"]}
            };
        });
    }
}
```